# Secure way to enable SVN calls using PHP?

Tags: php, apache, svn, shell

Is there a way to modify permissions on RHEL/Apache/PHP to enable, in a secure fashion, calls to SVN using shell commands - ie. shell_exec(), shell() or system() ?

At the moment, I get permission denied when attempting shell commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not obliged to use `exec()` calls and fabricate your own `svn add ...` commands since PECL has a stable PHP extension for this - [Subversion](http://php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php). The package [is here](http://pecl.php.net/package/svn).

This way you'll have an easy access to all needed SVN functionality inside your code.

Comment: Yup they are dangerous. Consider this, in order to use `exec()` on a Windows IIS (or whatever) you need to provide php with **full access to cmd**!? ... You have the ability to use [COM Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.com.php), which is the preferred method, as not to allow full cmd access. I always strive to host production apps on Unix/Linux as php was created in the Unix/Linux environment and this best suites it's security needs.

Comment: @borislavsabev what about the introduction message on that site that shows this is experimental, could change and use at your own risk? I'm trying to find out what version of SVN it supports...

Comment: Well it says **stable**.
Version - 1.0.2

State - stable

Release Date - 2012-03-27

Answer (score -1):

The only way i was able to achieve this was to use the SSH2 library and connect localy under a specific account. Else i was never able to set them up correctly.

---

It is not a good library, i had like 1 day to test out and search for documentation so it's definitely not the best way but at least it works...

Library currently in use:

```
<?php
/**
 * 
 * Runs several SSH2 commands on the devl server as root
 * 
 */
function ssh2Run(array $commands, $catchoutput = true, $server = 'localhost', $user = 'root', $logfile = NULL){

    //Open a log file for web output
    if($logfile == NULL){ $logfile = logCreate(); }

    //Connect to ssh2
    $connection = ssh2_connect($server);
    $hostkey = ssh2_fingerprint($connection);
    logWrite($logfile, 'Connected to '.$server.', hostkey = '.$hostkey);
    ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, $user, '/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub', '/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa');

    //Execute the various commands and read the output to the log file
    foreach($commands as $command){

        // Run a command that will probably write to stderr (unless you have a folder named /hom)
        logWrite($logfile, 'Sending command: '.$user.'@'.$server.': '.$command);
        logWrite($logfile, '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
        $outputStream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command, true);
        if(is_resource($outputStream)){
            stream_set_blocking($outputStream, true);
        }

        //Catch
        if($catchoutput){

            if(is_resource($errorStream)){
                $errorStream = ssh2_fetch_stream($outputStream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);
            }

            // Enable blocking for both streams
            if(is_resource($errorStream)){
                stream_set_blocking($errorStream, true);
            }

            // Whichever of the two below commands is listed first will receive its appropriate output.  The second command receives nothing
            logWrite($logfile, 'Output of command:');

            //Loop the stream until it is complete
            while((is_resource($outputStream) && !feof($outputStream)) || (is_resource($errorStream) && !feof($errorStream))){

                //Content read out
                if(is_resource($outputStream) && !feof($outputStream)){
                    $outputContent = trim(fgets($outputStream));
                }else{
                    $outputContent = '';
                }
                if(is_resource($errorStream) && !feof($errorStream)){
                    $errorContent = trim(fgets($errorStream));
                }else{
                    $errorContent = '';
                }

                //Add the information to the log
                if($outputContent == '' && $errorContent == ''){ continue; }
                if($outputContent !== ''){
                    logWrite($logfile, 'OUT: '.$outputContent);
                }
                if($errorContent !== ''){
                    logWrite($logfile, 'ERROR: '.$errorContent);
                }

            }

            // Close the streams       
            if(is_resource($errorStream)){ fclose($errorStream); }
            if(is_resource($outputStream)){ fclose($outputStream); }

        }

    }

    //Return the log
    return $logfile;

}

/**
 * 
 * List files in a SFTP enabled directory
 * 
 */
function sftpList($server, $user, $path){

    //Connect to ssh2
    $connection = ssh2_connect($server);
    $hostkey = ssh2_fingerprint($connection);
    ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, $user, '/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub', '/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa');

    //Create our SFTP resource
    if(!$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection)){
        throw new Exception('Unable to create SFTP connection.');
    }

    /**
      * Now that we have our SFTP resource, we can open a directory resource
      * to get us a list of files. Here we will use the $sftp resource in
      * our address string as I previously mentioned since our ssh2:// 
      * protocol allows it.
      */
    $results = array();
    $dirHandle = opendir('ssh2.sftp://'.$sftp.$path);
    while (false !== ($result = readdir($dirHandle))) {
        if ($result != '.' && $result != '..') {
            $results[] = $result;
        }
    }
    closedir($dirHandle);

    //Return the log
    return $results;

}
```

Comment: Would you have a small snippet to give me an idea of what it looks like?